# change vertex side of d3 network diagram in d3network package?

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, shiny, networkd3

Since current d3forcenetwork function does not accept parameter to change the size of vertex/node,
I searched the package and found MainForceJS() is controlling the layout and attempted to modify it.

However, when I try to override below section, the size attribute ('r') under circle class showed NaN value.

```
node.append(\"circle\")
.attr(\"r\", 6)
```

to

```
node.append(\"circle\")
.attr(\"r\", function(d) { return d.size;})
```

I also tried, but the console showed undefined for these circles.

```
.attr(\"r\",function(d) { console.log(d); console.log(d.size) })
```

The original code is for MainForceJS() function is listed here:
https://github.com/christophergandrud/d3Network/blob/cc224daa983e59dbe743c18e1ccb621bdd0ce509/R/templates.R

I have created a minimal example on github, the MainForceJS() function is in override.R and run either server.R or ui.R for execution.

https://github.com/happyshows/d3test

Answer (score 0):

I realized I also need to update the NodesDF in ForceNetwork() function, or the size attribute will be unknown to d3. I'm going to upload a new version to github so that people may find a working example.

```
  NodesDF <- data.frame(Nodes[, NodeID], Nodes[, Group], Nodes[, Size])
  names(NodesDF) <- c("name", "group","size")
```